# Streamwriter not throwing exception

Tags: c#

In the following, streamwriter is not throwing an exception if the file does not exist.
I expected it to raise an exception, why doesn't it and how can I get it to do so?

```
var fileName = HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/emails.txt");
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}\t{1}", email, name));
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Why?

Comment: Consider editing this post to include a question. For example "I expected it to raise an exception, why doesn't it and how can I get it to do so?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append);
```

This will create the file if it doesn't exist (and append to it if it does).

Assuming from your post (there is no question in it!) you don't want it to create a file first call `File.Exists` to ensure the file exists.

Comment: Or better, call `File.AppendText` to get the `StreamWriter` directly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure you're appending to an existing file, use `FileMode.Open` and then `Seek` to the end before writing.
With `File.Exists` there is a (very slim) chance of an other process deleting the file after checking but before the construction of the `FileStream`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
try
{
    var fileName = HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/emails.txt");
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName ))
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}\t{1}", email, name));
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
    else
    {
       //Throw error here
    }
}
catch()
{

}
```